# PHP Slim 3 .htaccess and index.php not working in subdirectory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, slim-3

I have a simple PHP Slim 3 project. Everything works fine and dandy when .htaccess and index.php are in root directory but I want to keep them in subdirectory "public". When I have them there, I get Error 404. It is not a mandatory thing but I want to keep everything in structure and know what is causing the error or how to fix it for future reference.

Project structure

```
root
 app
  controllers
 bootstrap
 logs
 public
  css
  js
 resources
 vendor
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

index.php

```
<?php
// Require application bootstrap
require __DIR__ . '/../bootstrap/app.php';

// Run Slim
$app->run();
```

Note: project is in remote server running on Apache

Comment: Your Apache `VirtualHost` should also point to `public` and not `root`.

Comment: I would try your solution but I am afraid that I won't be able to as remote server I am renting does not provide me with access to editing Apache configurations

Comment: Hosting plans usually provide a similar directory structure. They have a dedicated `private` and `public` folders.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [public directory for .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439784/public-directory-for-htaccess)

Comment: Have you tried this front controller? https://gist.github.com/odan/d2b889c350aa2ea0ff8e5ca93ce588a2#front-controller

Comment: https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/issues/2294#issuecomment-341887867

Comment: @DanielO. front controller seems to work. Is it ok to have more than one .htaccess file in project?

Comment: @Tomeister If you run your Slim app with Apache in a subdirectory, then yes :-) Please read also the "Container" section of this tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on your file
.htaccess should be something like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [QSA,L]
```

adding the public redirects it to the public folder
and for the index.php

index.php

should look like something like this when put into the public folder

```
<?php
// Require application bootstrap
require dirname(__DIR__). '/bootstrap/app.php';

// Run Slim
$app->run()
```

I hope this helps

Please also note with this simple help, there could be security concern as @Eric suggest in my comment, so extra work can be done, this is just to solve your current question, so as to reduce any headache it may be giving you

You can help address such security issue if you have access to your Virtual apache conf file, you can simply point your documentRoot to your public file and place your you previous .htaccess file in the public folder along side the index.php
but this time your .htaccess uses your previous configuration

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

when you don't have access lets say on a shared hosting with cpanel simply put your index.php file and .htaccess in your public_html, and put the rest of your application files and folder aside the necessary ones that need to be in the public_html folder such as your css, js and  images.

I hope this was much more helpful

Comment: There are security concerns with your answer. Files outside `public` can still be accessed. `public` folder is there for a reason.

Comment: Agreed, was just trying to give the person a solve to current situation, I do not plan to complicate things extra for the person, and I don't want to assume the person has extensive knowledge. but i will let the person know of the security tendencies

Comment: @Ezekiel - It's always better to address any security issues in the answers. If not, the OP might think it's totally fine and continue on building insecure apps. Let's help each other make better and more secure apps. :-)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thanks alot, I have taken it into notice, will let the person know right away, and the possible way to address such

Comment: @Eric I am a bit lost as I do not see where are those security concerns in this answer : /

Comment: Rule `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` means it will follow up physical files inside `root` folder which is a security concern.

Comment: It a security concern if you plan to hide the folders of your application, and if the person has an idea of your application structure, but nevertheless, use what suits your work best. I hope this question and answer, helps others also

Comment: `RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [QSA,L]` work but if it is a security concern, I might stick with front controller method Daniel O. suggested. Thanks for help

Comment: @Tomeister am glad this was helpful, Please note, this is only a thing of fear, whet n it generally boils down to how you want your application to function,  Such as cases where you have a main app already or this is a showcase(demo) app so in such case security may not necessarily be of utmost importance, I wish you all the best