# Remove Subfolder[Codeigniter] only for specified URLs using Htaccess

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My Folder Structure

- Root Domain

  - assets/ (contains css, images, js folders)
  - subfolder/ (contains Codeigniter Project inside and seperate .htaccess)
  - index.php
  - contact.php
  - .htaccess

**Root Htaccess**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)subfolder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subfolder/$1 [L]
```

**Subfolder(Codeigniter Project) Htaccess**

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|install|update)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# For godady Shared Hosting Server uncomment the line below
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]


</IfModule>
```

List of Subfolder URLs

- http://example.com/subfolder/products/
- http://example.com/subfolder/product/product-slug-123

List of Root URLs

- http://example.com/index.php
- http://example.com/contact.php

In my Codeigniter Project I've set `Products` controller as `default_controller`.
So the problem is, when I try to access the index.php page in the Root folder it only displays the Codeigniter products list as Home page.

I need following URLs:

- http://example.com/index.php
- http://example.com/contact.php
- http://example.com/products/
- http://example.com/product/product-slug-123

Any solutions with htaccess or with code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got this working.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !((.*)subfolder|^/assets) // to Exclude this
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (^/products(.*)|^/product(.*)) // to Include this
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subfolder/$1 [L]
```

> Exclamation(!) symbol used to 'not' matching urls.

So I removed Exclamation symbol and used another RewriteCond (Condition) to redirect only if the url contains segment as `products` or `product` http://example.com/products/ or http://example.com/product/product-slug-123. It's working perfectly now. I thought, sharing this would be useful to someone. Happy coding.